# Paramiko SSH start_server function raising EOF error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, networking, ssh, paramiko

I'm trying to implement an SSH server using paramiko but I keep getting an `EOFError` which I don't know why

```
class Ctx(paramiko.ServerInterface):
    def check_auth_password(self, username, password):
        if password == "1999":
            return paramiko.AUTH_SUCCESSFUL
        else:
            print("[+] Wrong Password...")
            return paramiko.AUTH_FAILED        
    def create_socket():
        sock = socket.socket()
        return sock
ctx = Ctx()
sock = Ctx.create_socket()
sock.bind(("127.0.0.1", 5555))
server = paramiko.Transport(sock)
server.start_server(server=ctx)
```

The error is caused by `start_server` which I can't see why. The traceback is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 26, in <module>
    server.start_server(server=ctx)
  File "/home/khaled/Documents/materials/python/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 728, in start_server
    raise e
  File "/home/khaled/Documents/materials/python/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 2034, in run
    self.packetizer.write_all(b(self.local_version + "\r\n"))
  File "/home/khaled/Documents/materials/python/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paramiko/packet.py", line 367, in write_all
    raise EOFError()
EOFError
```

The documentation doesn't show that `start_server` return `EOFError` instead it return `SSHException` same for `ServerInterface` class docs no mention of this error type only mention of it is in `socket()` which seems fine to me, it's binded to a port with no errors. Paramiko version is `2.7.2` installed in python virtual env.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy just edited the question with the version info. See last line. and there is no remote end everything is tested on same machine and I didnt try to connect. This error happens just by running program.

Comment: `write_all()` doesn't make any sense if you're just starting a listening socket.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy well this is weird I'm sure I'm not making any connections how can this happens. Is this a paramiko bug

Comment: First, creating a transport before you have any connections is just wrong. I very much doubt this is a paramiko bug; it looks like misuse of the API.

Comment: (a "transport" is a TCP connection between a SSH client and an SSH server; you can't make one, as a server, until after a client connected to you)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I dont think making a transport is wrong just quoting from documentation ```The high-level client API starts with creation of an SSHClient object. For more direct control, pass a socket (or socket-like object) to a Transport, and use start_server or start_client to negotiate with the remote host as either a server or client.``` while transport docs says ```Create a new SSH session over an existing socket, or socket-like object. This only creates the Transport object; it doesn’t begin the SSH session yet```

Comment: Read https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/blob/master/demos/demo_server.py for the right way to do it.

Comment: You'll see that it gets an incoming connection -- via `sock.accept()` -- **before** creating a transport.

Comment: BTW, if you think that the documentation you quoted above conflicts with anything I'm saying, feel free to explain why you believe it conflicts, and I'll try to address that misunderstanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't create a transport around the bind socket itself.

Accept a connection from a client, and create a transport around *that*.

To quote https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/blob/master/demos/demo_server.py, with exception handling removed for simplicity and some explanatory comments added --

```py
# first, we create our listening socket
# but we don't actually wrap it in a transport yet!
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sock.bind(("", 2200))

# next, tell the socket to start listening
# here, we're allowing up to a 100-connection backlog; tune to taste
sock.listen(100)

# here, we're blocking until a client actually connects
print("Listening for connection ...")
client, addr = sock.accept()

# only now, after we have a client, can we create a transport
print("Got a connection!")
t = paramiko.Transport(client, gss_kex=DoGSSAPIKeyExchange)
```

Comment: well this was not expected I thought paramiko would take care for all this since it didn't mention that in the documentation.

Comment: The demo server is part of the documentation.

Comment: @Khaled, ...and more to the point, any other design would be inflexible, because it would mean paramiko could only run directly over a real TCP socket, and couldn't be tunneled over other protocols.

Comment: not official docs site ```http://docs.paramiko.org/en/stable/index.html```. ```and more to the point, any other design would be inflexible``` No why not I already opened the socket and specified it's type it just had to listen and accept connections coming for it

Comment: @Khaled, _I already opened the socket and specified its type_ -- yes, but that's a _listen_ socket. If the paramiko code was written to work with listen sockets, then it couldn't work with preestablished sockets, unless you had a separate codepath and API. If you're only going to do one or the other, the preestablished approach is more flexible.